# Xamarin.Forms ListVew Data Triggers sporadically fail

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, datatrigger

I have a `ListView` composed of custom `ViewCell` in xaml. Simplified version below:

```
<ListView x:Name="myList" ItemTapped="myItemTapped" ItemsSource="{Binding myList}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout>
          <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="Quantity" TextColor="White"/>
            <Entry x:Name="QuantityEntry" BackgroundColor="White"/>

            <StackLayout.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True"/>
              </DataTrigger>
            </StackLayout.Triggers>
          </StackLayout>
          <StackLayout.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Gray"/>
            </DataTrigger>
          </StackLayout.Triggers>    
        </StackLayout>                      
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

`IsActive` is the property of the list Item that triggers the css change. `myItemTapped()` is a function that sets the item tapped `IsActive = true`.

Sporadically with no identifiable pattern, sometimes one or two items in the list will not show the `Entry` text box BUT its background css is changed to gray and its property `IsActive` is true.  It also doesnt always happen, sometimes they all work as they should.

[image]

**tldr; Expected: On tap of list item, background = gray & text box appears & x icon is shown**

**Actual: sporadically, sometimes only the background = gray & no text box & no x icon**

Any Ideas?